# How can I fill an html table data cell with a color?

Tags: html, bootstrap-table

I am creating a timeline with an html table. I want to colorize the data cells in a row corresponding to the lifespan of the person represented in a row. That is to say, if the person lived from 1835 to 1910, all of those columns would be colorized. Those prior to 1835, and those after 1910 would not.

I currently simply have a placeholder tilde as the contents of the "year" cells:

```
<tr>
      <th scope="row">John Marshall Clemens</th>
      <td>Father</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
```

The ultimate effect should look something like this (assuming John Marshall was alive at least from 1794 through 1797:

[image]

Comment: Are you manually creating this table? Or using some program to do so?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar: I am in the process of creating a utility that will convert a CSV file to the HTML

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using CSS classes

```css
.bg {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">John Marshall Clemens</th>
  <td>Father</td>
  <td class="bg">~</td>
  <td class="bg">~</td>
  <td class="bg">~</td>
  <td class="bg">~</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to use css,

```
<tr>
      <th scope="row">John Marshall Clemens</th>
      <td bgcolor="orange">Father</td>
      <td bgcolor="orange">~</td>
      <td bgcolor="orange">~</td>
      <td bgcolor="orange">~</td>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_bgcolor.asp

But I suggest reading and using CSS

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 4):

i hope this helps if its static.

```css
.bgColor{
  background-color: #ff7f28;
  color: #ff7f28;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Relation</th>
      <th>1794</th>
      <th>1795</th>
      <th>1796</th>
      <th>1797</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>fater</td>
      <td colspan="4" class="bgColor">~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>mark</td>
      <td>self</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>livy</td>
      <td>wife</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
      <td>~</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```